# Move and upgrade iPhoto 09 to iPhoto 11

Tags: mac, iphoto, ilife

I have an existing iPhoto 09 library on one Mac, I have another Mac with a iPhoto 11 library few photos in a, I'd like to move all the existing photos from 10 to 11 but preserve the albums and what not.

Can I do this without destroying what I currently have in 11 or should I just clean out my 11, import from 09 and then re-import the existing photos?

What's the best way to move the iPhoto 09 files, where is all the metadata kept?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use iPhoto Library Manager. Won't have to clear out 11 first.